# Who defined the term "Carleman-matrix" and also their properties as they are?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis

Working for a couple of years with "*[Carleman-matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix)*" I became aware that it is difficult to trace down who actually introduced the name for this type of matrices. Wikipedia lets you alone with this and a short question on the talk-page did not yet get attention/answer.

I found much literature using the term "Carleman-linearization" - but that's not enough to root the use of the term "Carleman-matrix"...

This is what I've found so far:

- (2000) The term "Carleman embedding matrices" was used by Gralewicz & Kowalski in "Continuous time evolution (...)" in 2000 (see arXiv-article [arXiv:math-ph/0002044](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002044))
- (1998) from:  Kowalski,K. : "[Nonlinear dynamical systems and Carleman Linearization](https://books.google.com/books?id=KmjnMu6Qe20C&pg=PA7)"
  *''In 1932 Carleman [3] following ideas of Poincaré and Fredholm demonstrated that nonlinear systems of ordinary differential equations with polynomial nonlinearities can be reduced to an infinite system of linear differential equations.  This approach is nowadays referred to as the Carleman linearization or Carleman embedding. (...)''

  ''[3] T. Carleman, Acta Mathematica 59, 63 (1932).''* https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.acta/1485887967
- (1991) Kowalski & Steeb : "Nonlinear dynamical systems and (...)" [pg. 121](https://books.google.com/books?id=KmjnMu6Qe20C&pg=PA121) *"and is called Carleman matrix of order two (...)"*
- (1985) N.N.Tarkhanov. "On the Carleman matrix for elliptic systems". Dokl. Acad. Nauk SSSR [Soviet Math.Dokl.], 284, No.2, 294-297 (1985). *(I have no access to that literature to scan the references)*
- (???)
- It was 1963 (if not before) Eri Jabotinsky introduced "representation-matrix" (with the variant of extending the row-/columnindex to negative infinity too, so this seems to be a more general convention than that which is given in wp for "Carleman-matrix" with lower indexes at zero) see "Analytic Iteration" in "transactions of the AMS" (at [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993593?origin=JSTOR-pdf)) especially pg. 431 .

So my question is:

> What is the canonical reference for the introduction of the term "Carleman-matrix" and of its properties?

Comment: There seems to be some discussion on the [talk page of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Carleman_matrix), but since the content seems to be rather similar to this post, I suppose the comments there comes from you.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: yes, this is true. I was searching earlier too, but in the earlier years I thought the wp entries would be enough when writing small essays. Now I tried a bit deeper and put my partial results on the talk-page but without reaction so far.